# php array count returns 1

Tags: php, arrays

i have this data which when tested with direct input it works and file_put_contents confrims that data is exactly same but when i try to get the value through site it gives only 1
i tried to declare array but everytime it gives 1 only

this array count gives count as 6

```
$total_id_counttt = count(array(13068,13067,13066,13065,13064,13063));
echo $total_id_counttt;
```

but when i use this here it return 1

```
$str_finalppo ='13068,13067,13066,13065,13064,13063';    
$schools_array = array($str_finalppo);
$total_id_counttt = count($schools_array);
```

it returns 1 can anyone tell where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Convert the string into an array. Look it in this code you may get the idea.

Use `explode` function to convert string to array.

```
$str_finalppo ='13068,13067,13066,13065,13064,13063';
$schools_array = explode(',',$str_finalppo);
$total_id_counttt = count($schools_array);
```

Check more about [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Pay attention. Do:  
$schools_array = ($str_finalppo != '') ? explode(",", $str_finalppo) : array();
Because count return 1 if string is empty

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, value in `quotes('')` consider as string.
So when you try to count this  is always returning the 1.

Try to convert the string into an array by using `explode()`.

for example:

```
$str_finalppo ='13068,13067,13066,13065,13064,13063';
$schools_array = explode(',',$str_finalppo);
echo $total_id_counttt = count($schools_array);
```

this will give you the right answer.
And  if you still confuse try to print `@schools_array` before using `dd($schools_array);`
It will definitely remove your confusion.